# Exponential decay of Riemann Zeta function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

It appears Riemann zeta function has a simple exponential tail behavior. I don't see this in the wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#:%7E:text=Definition,-Bernhard%20Riemann%27s%20article&text=The%20Riemann%20zeta%20function%20%CE%B6(s)%20is%20a%20function%20of,and%20t%20are%20real%20numbers.), is there an easy proof?

$$\zeta(ps) - 1 \xrightarrow[]{s \to \infty} 2^{-ps} \ \forall p>1 $$

[image]

```
SF = StringForm;
pvals = {1, 2, 3};
LogPlot @@ {Table[Zeta[p s] - 1, {p, pvals}], {s, 1, 50}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"steps", "error"}, 
  PlotLegends -> (SF["p=``", #] & /@ pvals), WorkingPrecision -> 50}
```

Comment: You can prove this directly from the Dirichlet series expansion.